# my windows laptop donot detect the closing of the lid?

Tags: windows, laptop, sleep

I have a compaq cq45 laptop running on windows 8.1. The problem is when i close the lid of my laptop it does nothing neither sleep nor shutdown even the setting is set to sleep . The lights also donot goes off  its like same lid open or closed . The movement of lid is not detected . How can it be solved ??

Comment: does it go to sleep if you select sleep from the power menu(Top right corner on the start page) ??OR by pressing the keys ALT +F4 and selecting sleep ??

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, use the physical button to put the laptop to sleep.(choose what pressing the power button does)

- Re-install your graphics drivers.
- OR do a clean install of windows 8.1 and make sure you have the correct graphics drivers installed.

  - Check that you have not created any custom power plan(just below choose what closing the lid does,if you have delete it).
- If it still doesn't work, might be a hardware issue and you will need to take it for repair.

Answer (score -1):

Check the Windows Power Options. Look at "Choose what closing the lid does" and make sure the setting is correct. That would be the most likely cause.

Update the Power Management driver to the newest version also.

Comment: They said the setting was set for sleep on lid close.